# TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting python in if-else loop

Tags: python, string, if-statement, typeerror

This porgram is supposed split a string into two different strings where the even indices are in `message1` and odd indices are in `message2`. There seems to be an error in the code in the `if` statment in line 7.

```
input_str = 'bmaunmdbraai'
#Type your code here
message1 = input_str[0]

for i in range(0, len(input_str)):
    if (input_str[i] % 2 == 0):
        message1 = message1 + input_str[i]
    else:
        message2 = message2 + input_str[i]

print(message1, message2)
```

The error message:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-31-28323eb4095a> in <module>
      5 
      6 for i in range(0, len(input_str)):
----> 7     if (input_str[i] % 2 == 0):
      8         message1 = message1 + input_str[i]
      9     else:

TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to modulus the index, not the char itself

```
if (input_str[i] % 2 == 0):
```

should be

```
if (i % 2 == 0):
```

For what it's worth this can be done more concisely using slicing

```
message1 = input_str[::2]   # even
message2 = input_str[1::2]  # odd
```

Comment: Wow! Thanks so much.. But now there seems to be a error ```

Comment: ```NameError: name 'message2' is not defined```

Comment: But when I defined by assigning a value like ```message2 = input_str[1]```. Then the first letter in both messages is printed twice.

Comment: @NishanthNair Just initialize both to empty string `message1 = ''` and `message2 = ''`

Comment: Great!! Worked like a charm.